# Where can I download chrome-stable-current?

Tags: updates, google-chrome, ppa, chromium, 32-bit

I installed Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 from an old .deb package, but now I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when trying to load any Google site (*.google.com, where * can be mail, plus, contacts, etc.).

Trying

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
ERROR 404: Not Found
```

Can anyone tell me a reliable site whence to download this package? The Google PPA doesn't work any more. Presumably, Google has abandoned all users with old but serviceable 32-bit laptops.

Even a 32-bit chrome beta .deb package will do.

Launchpad has [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1547762?comments=all) for libnss3 which may be part of the problem. In my case, Chromium works okay but not Chrome, which appears to be the opposite experience to many other Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome no longer provides 32bit versions for Linux.  They also pulled all *legitimate* installers.  Their reasons are something along the lines of a small Linux team not willing to support all systems when the standard is 64-bit, I believe.

You cannot get Chrome 32-bit for Linux anymore.  It is simply not possible.  And anyone providing links to installation packages I would not trust for security reasons.

Comment: Can anyone make a copy of their downloaded package available? Although, as Thomas W. says, this is not a good idea. 8^)

Comment: Why don't you go for chromium?

Comment: @HedleyFinger Pretty likely not a good idea because you lose all security updates.  If you are still using an ancient 32bit platform you may wish to consider updating your computers to match the modern day architecture standards for computers if you want 64bit chrome.  Chromium didn't ever drop 32bit support - you just have to compile it as Ubuntu and others do.

Comment: Don't tell me the Google developers have lost their 32-bit compile script from previous releases? In a dev shop in which I worked both the testing and compilation were automated to run overnight. How hard is it really? Looks like Chromium will have to do.

Comment: @HedleyFinger Whether they did or didn't they chose to stop supporting 32bit and don't provide a compile script - they also don't provide source code for Chrome so it's not something we can fix nor anyone can fix.

Comment: @HedleyFinger No need to go on the offensive you know... being rude doesn't help anything.

Comment: @HedleyFinger no need to be starting comments war, that's first of all. Second of all, avoid 32-bit chrome at all cost - that's my advice. There will be tons and tons of blackhat hackers now that will be just waiting to take over your computer. **You might not care about that, but other people care , server admins of your favorite sites care ; so don't make your machine part of botnet mafia.**  Third, if you absolutely need to use chrome, consider upgrading your os to 64 bit version.

Comment: @Serg replace OS with Computer in your comment - they have a 32bit PC if I am not mistaken

Comment: @ThomasW. If CPU is 64 bit capable, they can use 64 bit OS , and has nothing to do with a computer model - type - etc.

Comment: @Serg You say that as if I don't know that.  Reread their original post and read the part about 'serviceable 32bit laptops'